# How to find the URL/Public IP to access the server run by a Docker container, from my website on any network

Tags: docker, networking

I have set up a node.js server and run it in a Docker container.
I am hosting MySQL database on my computer and have the server connected.
I have deployed my website on netlify and it uses REST API to send and retrieve data to the server.

Currently, the API url uses 'http://localhost:4941/api/v1...' When I access the website on the same computer as the database is hosted, I am able to see the data retrieved from the server.

However, when I access the website on another computer (and from a different network), I am not able to see the data obtained from the server.

I have tried using 127.0.0.1 as well as the Docker container's IPAddress of 172.17.0.2 but was unable to solve the problem too.

I expect to be able to use my website from any computers in the world that have access to Internet and be able to send and retrieve data from the server.

So, does the problem lie in the API url of me using localhost? If so, what address should I use instead?

Comment: What does this have to do with Vue?

Comment: It's exactly the same as if you had installed Node on the host and there was no Docker involved at all; it's not `localhost` because that's always "this computer" or "this container".  The Docker-private IP addresses are basically useless and you never need to look them up.

Comment: @DavidMaze so do I have to do port forwarding and all the other usual stuff?

Comment: @DavidWeldon thank you for pointing it out, i have changed the tag to node.js

Comment: You will always need a `docker run -p` option or equivalent.  Once you've done that, the container is indistinguishable from any other service running on the host; if you need to set up a port forward in a border router for a plain Node process, then you need to do it for a Docker-wrapped Node process as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'll work on it, thank you for the advice!

Comment: @KaiKoh Please expose docker container port to your machine.
Like this ```docker run -p 4941:4941 <Image_name>``` Then you will be able to access this on your ```localhost```